# How can I set Windows audio balance levels programmatically?

Tags: c#, audio, audio-recording, naudio

I'm dealing with sound software and I'm setting the default Audio device using nircmd.exe perfectly, but I also need to adjust the balance levels, either using a similar tool (since nircmd.exe doesn't handle that) or programatically using C#.

[image]

I've seen NAudio has a read-only property that reads the values

```
defaultDevice.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[0]; //i.e. left channel
```

But there's no setter for that.

Is there any familiar way to achieve this?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found the answer.

```
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;

MMDeviceEnumerator devEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

MMDevice defaultDevice = devEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Capture, Role.Communications);

defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Channels[0].VolumeLevel = 10;
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Channels[1].VolumeLevel = 6;
```